# Saving RDD's in for loop in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a for loop in which i end up with a RDD for every iteration, which i want to save for later use. What is the most efficient way to save and access these RDDs?

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Is the current way inefficient? If yes, how?

Comment: Hi
I might not have been clear enough.
I have a a for loop, lets say from 1 to 10. For each iterration i want to save a RDD, which i want to access after the whole for loop is done.
So when the for loop is done i want to be able to access RDD1, RDD2...... RDD10.

Comment: did you try using yield?

Comment: Will try to do that. Thanks!

Comment: In the for loop i also have to do some transformations on other RDDs, including to save the prefferd RDD so im not sure if you can do that when using yield. So i dont think yield will work

Comment: Can you post some sample code or psuedocode?

Comment: @CoMacNo: So do you already have an yield statement or is the transformation and saving a mutating operation, a side effect?

Answer (score 0):

Samplecode, without RDD and spark specifics:

```
scala> val res = (for (i <- (1 to 10);
     |  j=2*i;
     |  k= s"i: $i j: $j") yield k)
res: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[String] = Vector(i: 1 j: 2, i: 2 j: 4, i: 3 j: 6, i: 4 j: 8, i: 5 j: 10, i: 6 j: 12, i: 7 j: 14, i: 8 j: 16, i: 9 j: 18, i: 10 j: 20)

scala> res(0)
res201: String = i: 1 j: 2

scala> res(1)
res202: String = i: 2 j: 4
```

So just yield your RDDs, and collect them in a Seq for universal later usage.

You may as well yield multiple vals

```
yield (i, j, k)
```

and deconstruct the tupleN later, filter it, group, and so on.